# How to navigate through an array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to create a code  that when y/n is input by the user, the user will go to the next entry in the array. and when they reach the end of the array, the user will go back to the start of the array and so on. This is my code so far. I've researched this a lot but still have no idea what to do.
    just to be clear i'm needing help on looping through the array while also allowing the users input to choose where to do.

```
#declaring array names.
longitude=[]; latitude=[]; messagetext=[];encryptions=[];
input_file = open('messages.txt', 'r')


lines_in_file_array = input_file.read().splitlines()


#appending the lines in a select file to select records.
for line in lines_in_file_array:
     record_array = line.split(',')
     longitude.append(record_array[0])
     latitude.append(record_array[1])
     messagetext.append(record_array[2])

input_file.close()

def encrypt():
    temporary_array=[]
    for index in range(len(messagetext)):
        x=messagetext[index]
        x=([ord(character)+2 for character in x])
        codedx=''.join([chr(character) for character in x])
        temporary_array.append(codedx)
        print(codedx)

def navigation():
    continues=False
    while continues == True:




encrypt()
print(messagetext)
```

Comment: `input("see next element (y/n)")` will get you started.

Comment: Do you need help with just the looping part, or also taking in the input? I don't see the latter, but I also don't see you asking for help with that part.

Comment: Both. i'll edit my question now.

Answer (score 0):

To get user entry, use [input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) as follows:

```
answer = input("See next entry ? (y/n)" )
if answer == "y":
    #do the stuff
```

You could use [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) to cycle your entry, this way:

```
from itertools import cycle

lines_in_file_array = input_file.read().splitlines()

lines_in_file_array = cycle(lines_in_file_array)

...
```

Then, you can loop infinitely:

```
for line in lines_in_file_array:
    ....
```

and go back at the beginning of your array till you reach the end

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which array you want to navigate in, but to make the navigation with user input:

```
def navigation():
    i = 0
    continues = True
    user = input("Continue?y/n")
    if user == "y":
        while continues:
             print array[i]
             i = (i+1)%len(array)
             user = input("Continue?y/n")
             if user != "y":
                 continues = False
```

Comment: Continue is a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with only a few lines of code, once you have your arrays.

```
# Index counter
i = 0;

# Loop forever
while True:

    # Get the user's input, and store the response in answer
    answer = input("See next entry (y/n)? ")

    # If the user entered "y" or "Y"
    if answer.lower() == "y":

        # print the message
        print(messagetext[i % len(messagetext)])

        # and increment the index counter
        i = i + 1

    # Otherwise leave the loop
    else:
        break
```